# Residue field of a local ring as field extension

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, extension-field, krull-dimension

> Let $k$ be a field, $A$ a finitely generated commutative $k$-algebra and $\mathfrak p$ a prime ideal of $A$. Let $K$ be the residue field of the local ring $A_\mathfrak{p}$. I want to show that $K$ is a field extension of $k$ and $\mathrm{tr.deg}(K/k) \leq\dim A$.

I know that $K \cong \operatorname{Quot}(A/\mathfrak p)$. Also there is a canonical homomorphism $k \rightarrow A \twoheadrightarrow A/\mathfrak p\hookrightarrow \operatorname{Quot}(A/\mathfrak p)$, but I don't know why (or if) that is injective.

Any hints?

Comment: A ring map between fields is *always* injective.

Comment: What do you know about dimension? Do you know the connection between transcendence degree and dimension of domains of finite type over fields?

Comment: Is $A$ commutative ?

Comment: I know that the dimension of a finitely generated, integral algebra $A$ over a field $k$ equals the transcendence degree of the $\operatorname{Quot}(A)$ over $k$. And since $\mathfrak p$ is prime, $A/\mathfrak p$ is integral, and finitely generated because $A$ is finitely generated. So $\dim A/\mathfrak p = \mathrm{tr.deg}(K/k)$. And because $\dim A = \sup_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec}(A)} \dim(A/\mathfrak p)$, the inequality holds. Is that correct?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Not necessarily.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry. Of course it is commutative. We only work with commutative rings, and I somehow did not notice, that an algebra is a ring too, so algebra implies commutative, too.

Comment: In the commutative case, after the remarks and the end of the question and  Keenan's comment there is nothing more to say right ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I think not. Thank you all.

Comment: Dear @Alex R., It's helpful if you always include everything you know that might be relevant to the problem (e.g. the relationship between transcendence degree and dimension for domains). This helps the potential responders to you question to formulate an appropriate response, and saves them time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the dimension of a domain of finite type over $k$ is equal to the transcendence degree of its fraction field, then you know that $\dim(A/\mathfrak{p})=\mathrm{tr.deg}_k(K)$. Can you show using the definition of dimension that $\dim(A/\mathfrak{p})\leq\dim(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

As Keenan pointed out, the composition of maps you gave injects $k$ into $\text{Quot}(A/\mathfrak{p})$.

For comparing $\text{tr. deg}(K/k)$ to $\dim A$, my hint is to use Noether Normalization, a result which, if you don't know now, is well worth learning.